# Can avahi daemon be used to publish and discover service in BNEP(BT-PAN) network Interface

Tags: linux, bluetooth, mdns, jmdns, avahi

Can avahi daemon be used to publish and discover service in BNEP network Interface ? 
If two devices are tethered in Bluetooth then both devices will have IP, so we can do TCP-IP communication between them.
Actually I want to do mDNS Service Discovery in cross platform (Android and Linux). In Android, I can publish and discover services in BNEP (BT-PAN) network interface using NSDManager of Android and it also works in Android cross-device communication. So android to android device communication is not a problem.

Now I am trying to discover the service in Linux which is published in Android and discover from linux(or vice versa), but I am not able to do that. [I have tethered my Linux device with Android]

In linux, in avahi config( /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf), I set to 
allow-interfaces=bnep0

In discovering services from Linux, I cannot find the services published. Or I also cannot find the services in Android which are published in Linux.

Have anyone faced this type of issue before ?
and I am trying to discover services published in bnep